# .reg File-Created DSN Works But Does Not Display in Data Sources (ODBC)

Tags: odbc, registry, windows-7-x64

If I double-click on a registry key file that contains the following

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI\permits_db_conn_new_app]
    "Driver"="c:\\Windows\\system32\\sqlncli10.dll"
    "Description"="New ODBC Connector for Inspectional Services Permits Applications"
    "Server"="ARLINGTON_SERV"
    "Database"="BuildingPermit"
    "LastUser"="ispermits"
```

the registry updates properly, and my C# application that uses the DSN `permits_db_conn_new_app` works fine.

If I delete that key and then re-create the key using Data Sources (ODBC), that DSN also works fine.

My problem is the first key created by double-left-mouse clicking on the .reg file won't show up in Data Sources (ODBC). I'm trying to figure out why, and I have compared the two keys and found nothing significantly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the little ODBC applet --  Data Sources (ODBC) -- performs one more task after creating a DNS registry entry. It puts an entry for your DSN into `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources]`, which allows your newly created DSN to show up in  Data Sources (ODBC).